# Is there a way to get a figure to fit the size of a table object?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a function that can take in a pandas data frame and create a matplotlib table figure for it. The size of the data frames being passed in can range from 1 to 25 rows so the figure sizing needs to be versatile. However, I am running into an issue with the figure size and axes size not matching the size of the table object I created using the pandas data frame.

So far, I have tried turning the axes on and off, turning frame attribute on and off for the figure and the axis, pulling the width and height of the table and resizing the figure to match the table, and using tight_layout(). I have also tried all these different solutions while placing the table at different locations on the figure.

Here is the current state of my code:

```
def create_table_fig(df):
    fig = plt.figure(frameon = False)
    table = plt.table(cellText = df.values, colLabels = df.columns, fontsize = 'large', loc = 'lower left')
    table.auto_set_column_width(col=list(range(len(df.columns))))
    table.set_figure(fig)
    plt.close()
    
    return fig
```

```
data = {'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dave'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
    'Salary': [50000, 60000, 70000, 80000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
table = create_table_fig(df)
table
```

#### This is what I keep getting

[image: This is what I keep getting:]

#### This is what I'm trying to get

[image: This is what I'm trying to get:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the figure is set using the figsize argument in plt.subplots(). The height of the figure is set based on the number of rows in the data frame, so that each row has a height of 0.4. The axes are turned off using ax.axis('off'), and the table is created with a bbox that spans the entire figure using bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1]. Finally, plt.tight_layout() is called to adjust the spacing between the table and the edge of the figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def create_table_fig(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, len(df) * 0.4))
    ax.axis('off')
    table = ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns,
                     fontsize='large', cellLoc='center', bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1])
    table.auto_set_column_width(col=list(range(len(df.columns))))
    plt.tight_layout()

    return fig


data = {'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dave'],
        'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
        'Salary': [50000, 60000, 70000, 80000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
table = create_table_fig(df)
plt.show()
```